# Efficient and elegant way to fill values in pandas column based on each groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'person_id': [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5],
    'obs_date': ['12/31/2007', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', '11/25/2009', '10/15/2019', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA']
})
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

What I would like to do is replace/fill `NA` type rows with actual date values from the same group. For which I tried the below

```
m1 = df_new['obs_date'].str.contains('^\d')
df_new['obs_date'] = df_new.groupby((m1).cumsum())['obs_date'].transform('first')
```

But this gives an unexpected output like shown below

[image]

Here for the 2nd row it should have been `11/25/2009` from person_id = 3 instead it is from the 1st group of person_id = 1.

How can I get the expected output as shown below

[image]

Any elegant and efficient solution is helpful as I am dealing with more than million records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non datetimes to missing values, then [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for get first non missing value in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) new column filled by data:

```
df_new['obs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['obs_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
df_new['obs_date'] = df_new.groupby('person_id')['obs_date'].transform('first')
#alternative - minimal value per group
#df_new['obs_date'] = df_new.groupby('person_id')['obs_date'].transform('min')

print (df_new)
   person_id   obs_date
0          1 2007-12-31
1          1 2007-12-31
2          3 2009-11-25
3          3 2009-11-25
4          5 2019-10-15
5          5 2019-10-15
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df_new['obs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['obs_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
df_new['obs_date'] = (df_new.sort_values(['person_id','obs_date'])
                            .groupby('person_id')['obs_date']
                            .ffill())

print (df_new)
   person_id   obs_date
0          1 2007-12-31
1          1 2007-12-31
2          3 2009-11-25
3          3 2009-11-25
4          5 2019-10-15
5          5 2019-10-15
```

Comment: But where is `GroupBy.first` is used?

Comment: `.transform('first')`

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475086/elegant-way-to-fill-in-a-column-with-row-values-based-on-groups-in-pandas/57475346#57475346

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `pd.to_datetime(..,errors='coerce')` to fill non date values as `NaT` and `ffill` and `bfill` after groupby :

```
df_new['obs_date']=(df_new.assign(obs_date=pd.to_datetime(df_new['obs_date'],
 errors='coerce')).groupby('person_id')['obs_date'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
print(df_new)
```

---

```
   person_id   obs_date
0          1 2007-12-31
1          1 2007-12-31
2          3 2009-11-25
3          3 2009-11-25
4          5 2019-10-15
5          5 2019-10-15
```

Comment: @jezrael I see what you mean. Thanks. then `apply()` is a way

Comment: Hello @anky_91 - Can help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550238/elegant-and-efficient-way-retain-date-values-as-is-without-oob-error

Comment: Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667919/how-to-build-custom-operation-as-a-calculator-to-handle-million-rows-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

```
df_new= df_new.join(df_new.groupby('person_id')["obs_date"].min(),
                    on='person_id',
                    rsuffix="_clean")
```

Output:

```
   person_id           obs_date obs_date_clean
0          1         12/31/2007     12/31/2007
1          1  NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA     12/31/2007
2          3  NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA     11/25/2009
3          3         11/25/2009     11/25/2009
4          5         10/15/2019     10/15/2019
5          5  NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA     10/15/2019
```

Comment: where do I see the suffix `_min`? Thanks for the answer.upvoted

Comment: sorry, suffix should be `_clean`