# Elegant way to fill in a column with row values based on groups in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as given below

```
data_file= pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'ob.date': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                 'observation': ['Age','interviewdate','marital_status','interviewdate','Age','interviewdate','marital_status','Age','interviewdate','marital_status'],
                 'answer': [21,'21/08/2017','Single','22/05/2217', 26,'11/03/2010','Single',41,'31/09/2012','Married']
                 })
```

[image]

What I would like to do is, fetch the `date values` from `answer` column and put it in `ob.date` column. The dataframe provided shows that `person_id =1` answered question about Age on `21/08/2017` and on `22/05/2017` he answered question about `marital_status`

This is what I tried based on SO suggestion from another post

```
s = data_file[(data_file.observation == 'interviewdate')].set_index('person_id')['answer']
data_file['ob.date'] = data_file['person_id'].map(s)
```

But this does not work as I get `duplicate index error`. How can I avoid that issue and make it efficient enough?

So any elegant and efficient solution would be helpful. Person_id = 1 has two date values, so fill all rows above `interviewdate` observation with the value from `answer` column (of `interviewdate` observation)

How can I expect my output to be like this?

[image]

Comment: What is the policy for the first `person_id` ? Fill all row above `interviewdate` by the matching date ?

Comment: Yes. Above. you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All depends of data - first set new column by `answer` by condition and then per groups repalce missing values by back and forward filling:

```
data_file['ob.date']  = data_file.loc[(data_file.observation == 'interviewdate'), 'answer']
data_file['ob.date'] = (data_file.groupby('person_id')['ob.date']
                                 .apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))


print (data_file)

   person_id     ob.date     observation      answer
0          1  21/08/2017             Age          21
1          1  21/08/2017   interviewdate  21/08/2017
2          1  22/05/2217  marital_status      Single
3          1  22/05/2217   interviewdate  22/05/2217
4          2  11/03/2010             Age          26
5          2  11/03/2010   interviewdate  11/03/2010
6          2  11/03/2010  marital_status      Single
7          3  31/09/2012             Age          41
8          3  31/09/2012   interviewdate  31/09/2012
9          3  31/09/2012  marital_status     Married
```

**Details**:

First is used back fiiling per groups, because `interviewdate` are edge rows - all values before are same subgroups. Last is add forwrd filling for repalce last NaNs per groups - not replaced by `bfill`:

```
data_file['ob.date'] = (data_file.groupby('person_id')['ob.date']
                                   .apply(lambda x: x.bfill()))


print (data_file)

   person_id     ob.date     observation      answer
0          1  21/08/2017             Age          21
1          1  21/08/2017   interviewdate  21/08/2017
2          1  22/05/2217  marital_status      Single
3          1  22/05/2217   interviewdate  22/05/2217
4          2  11/03/2010             Age          26
5          2  11/03/2010   interviewdate  11/03/2010
6          2         NaN  marital_status      Single
7          3  31/09/2012             Age          41
8          3  31/09/2012   interviewdate  31/09/2012
9          3         NaN  marital_status     Married
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but what if the interview date comes before the corresponding observation for a person with multiple interview dates (e.g. row 0 and 1 swapped)? This solution will fill in the interview date for the next question to this person which is probably not what the OP intended: he wrote **solution which doesn't rely on positions**.

Comment: @Stef - yes - and it is reason why start explanation by `All depends of data`

Comment: I marked this as a solution as data has to be in some structure to code. Hence I removed the constraint about position from my question

Comment: Can you help me with this @jezrael? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550238/elegant-and-efficient-way-retain-date-values-as-is-without-oob-error