# Elegant and Efficient way retain date values as is without OOB error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which is like as shown below

```
df1_new = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5],'obs_date': ['7/23/2377  12:00:00 AM', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', '7/27/2277  12:00:00 AM', '7/13/2077  12:00:00 AM', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA']})
```

[image]

As you can see few of my date values are `out of bound` values. However, I would still like to retain them as it is. Unfortunately, I couldn't due to OOB issue

I tried below

```
pd.to_datetime(df1_new['obs_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
```

[image]

Is there any other efficient way to retain the date value as is but by changing the format alone? I am fine if it can be string column/datatype

I expect my output to be like as shown below.

[image]

**updated try/except screenshot**

[image]

Comment: pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years. which means dates with year 2377 and 2277 cannot be converted to datetime. try changing these dates and it will work.

Comment: Actually my real data has more than million records like this. It's did to de-identify the original dates. Isn't there any other way to do this? Instead of having them as datetime, something with string approach

Comment: I cannot change the dates for my scenario to become in-bound. I have to work with whatever date values I have.

Comment: Check my solution. Hope that will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert values to datetimes and then to day `Period` for only possible format in pandas for represent `out of bound` values.

If omit it, then working with python datetimes objects, not with pandas datetimes (timestamps).

```
from datetime import datetime
def str2time(x):
    try:
        return pd.Period(datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'), 'D')
    except:
        return np.nan

df1_new['obs_date'] = df1_new['obs_date'].apply(str2time)
print(df1_new)
   person_id    obs_date
0          1  2377-07-23
1          1         NaT
2          3         NaT
3          3  2277-07-27
4          5  2077-07-13
5          5         NaT

print(df1_new['obs_date'].dtype)
period[D]
```

If possible multiple formats:

```
def str2time(x):
    try:
        #MM/DD/YYYY II:MM:SS pp like 7/23/2377  12:00:00 AM
        return pd.Period(datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'), 'D')
    except:
        try:
            #YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS like 2377-07-23 00:00:00
            return pd.Period(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'D')
        except:
            return np.nan

df1_new['obs_date'] = df1_new['obs_date'].apply(str2time)
```

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, not easy working with this kind of data

Comment: Trying now. was away for a meeting

Comment: @SSMK - No problem;)

Comment: I had an issue. It goes into both Try and Except block. Only if there is an error, it should go to except block. Am I right? updated the screenshot in post

Comment: The format is different, so I have updated the format alone. my input date values looks like this `2175-04-07 00:00:00`

Comment: @SSMK - one idea - is possible extract this problematic column to csv and share? Because really hard test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198120/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).