# How to format datetime values in columns without to_datetime functions in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
df1_new = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5],'obs_date': ['7/23/2377  12:00:00 AM', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', '7/27/2277  12:00:00 AM', '7/13/2077  12:00:00 AM', 'NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA']})
```

[image]

I would not like to use `pd.to_datetime` approach because of year constraint (upper limit) it imposes. [OOB error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550238/elegant-and-efficient-way-retain-date-values-as-is-without-oob-error?noredirect=1#comment101563798_57550238)

The below is what I tried but it isn't efficient as you can see below

```
yr = df1_new['obs_date'][0][5:9]
m = df1_new['obs_date'][0][2:4]
d = df1_new['obs_date'][0][0]
t = df1_new['obs_date'][0][11:19]
output = yr + "-" + m + "-" + d + " " + t
```

Is there any other efficient and elegant way to achieve the below expected output without using `pd.datetime` functions

[image]

**updated screenshot**

[image]

**try/except screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Did you try `strptime()` and `strftime()` functions? - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Doesn't that require column to be of datatime object?

Comment: No. It requires the column to be in `string` format.

Comment: If you can write the answer, I can upvote it.

Comment: Marking @tawab_shakeel answer as solution as it had `Try/catch blocks` which handled the error when compared to rest of the answers (which threw error for NA scenarios)). Nonetheless all the answers are quite correct and appreciate their response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply try catch when converting string into datetime

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def str2time(x):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    except:
        return pd.NaT

df1_new['obs_date'] = df1_new['obs_date'].apply(str2time)
print(df1_new)
```

```
     person_id             obs_date
0          1  2377-07-23 12:00:00
1          1                  NaT
2          3                  NaT
3          3  2277-07-27 12:00:00
4          5  2077-07-13 12:00:00
5          5                  NaT
```

Comment: I have a quick question. let's say my input date is like this `2175-04-07 00:00:00`, I modify the function to look like this `return datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` but this returns `NaT` as output. Can you let me know what can be the issue?

Comment: `res = datetime.datetime.strptime('2175-04-07 00:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` if you are doing this it is correct

Comment: Exactly, it's same as what you have given but the result is `NaT`

Comment: Solution is wrong, `%H:%M:%S %p` need `%I:%M:%S %p`

Comment: What is the difference between `%H` and `%I`. When I use `%I`, it throws error

Comment: Updated screenshot

Comment: `I` is used with `p`, because it is 12 hours format - http://strftime.org/

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you

Comment: @tawab_shakeel - Can you please help me fgure out what's the issue? As you can see in another `try/except` updated screenshot that it enters both try and catch blocks. Not sure what is the issue

Comment: so try block would always run if there is an error in try block then it jumps to except block

Comment: @tawab_shakeel - Can you help me with this post? Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667919/how-to-build-custom-operation-as-a-calculator-to-handle-million-rows-efficiently

Comment: @SSMK question is deleted

Comment: @tawab_shakeel - Can you look at this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703423/how-to-get-minimum-of-each-group-for-each-day-based-on-hour-criteria

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string date to datetime and then back to the format you want. Example below:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = "7/23/2377 12:00:00 AM"
datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p")

#output
>>>'2377-07-23 00:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: Would you mind modifying your answer to suit the expected output? I am trying as well. It will be useful for others as well

Comment: Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667919/how-to-build-custom-operation-as-a-calculator-to-handle-million-rows-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_func(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df1_new['obs_date'] = df1_new['obs_date'].astype(str)
df1_new['obs_date'] = df1_new['obs_date'].apply(convert_func)
```

This should work

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: @SSMK `import datetime; datetime.datetime.strptime`. That's why there is a `from` in the answer.

Comment: @SSMK Please check if you would have already imported datetime functions with some other name to your environment. If the error persists, restart console once and import again as per above code

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf - Can you help me with this? Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667919/how-to-build-custom-operation-as-a-calculator-to-handle-million-rows-efficiently