# How to get minimum of each group for each day based on hour criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vectorization, pandas-groupby

I have given two dataframes below for you to test

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 17:00:00','2173-04-03 
         20:00:00','2173-04-04 11:00:00','2173-04-04 11:30:00','2173-04-04 
       12:00:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 
       04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 06:30:00'],
  'val' :[5,5,5,10,5,10,5,8,3,8,10]
 })


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-03 
           12:59:00','2173-04-03 13:14:00','2173-04-03 13:37:00','2173-04-04 
           11:30:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 
           04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 08:00:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,5,5,10,5,5,8,3,4,6]
 })
```

what I would like to do is

1) Find all values (from `val` column) which have been `same for more than 1 hour` in `each day for each subject_id` and get the `minimum of it`

Please note that **values can also be captured at `every 15 min duration` as well, so you might have to consider 5 records to see `> 1 hr` condition**). See sample screenshot below

2) If there are no values which were `same for more than 1 hour` in a day, then just get the `minimum of that day for that subject_id`

The below screenshot for one subject will help you understand and the code I tried is given below

[image]

This is what I tried

```
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['time_2'] = df['time_1'].shift(-1)
df['tdiff'] = (df['time_2'] - df['time_1']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
df['reading_day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time_1']).day

# don't know how to apply if else condition here to check for 1 hr criteria
t1 = df.groupby(['subject_id','reading_start_day','tdiff])['val'].min()
```

As I have to apply this to million records, any elegant and efficient solution would be helpful

Comment: Correct syntax: `df.groupby(['subject_id','reading_start_day','tdiff])['val'].min() if tdiff > 1 else do_something`

Comment: But that doesn't give the expected output

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Are you sure that's the syntax? It doesn't work

Comment: What is df['time_2']? I don't see time_2 column in the above dataframes..

Comment: I have created that column in code. Refer my code

Comment: The correct syntax for the in-line if-else condition is `do_something if condition else do_some_other_thing`

Comment: Share a chat room link

Comment: Hope you got my message in chat

Comment: I do not understand what is meant by `sustained for more than 1 hour`

Comment: Value should be same for more than 1 hour

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: I cannot join chat due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: The answer you have put & the dataframe you have put don't match. for example in df, there are no 3 in the data you posted but 3 in the picture.

Comment: updated the post @mohanys. I hope it helps. I have given two dataframes to test. You can use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 17:00:00','2173-04-03 20:00:00','2173-04-04 11:00:00','2173-04-04 11:30:00','2173-04-04 12:00:00','2173-04-04 16:00:00','2173-04-04 22:00:00','2173-04-05 04:00:00','2173-04-05 06:30:00'],
  'val' :[5,5,5,10,5,10,5,8,8,10]
 })

# Separate Date and time
df['time_1']=pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['new_date'] = [d.date() for d in df['time_1']]
df['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in df['time_1']]


# find time diff in group with the first element to check > 1 hr
df['shift_val'] = df['val'].shift()
df1=df.assign(time_diff=df.groupby(['subject_id','new_date']).time_1.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]))

# Verify if time diff > 1 and value is not changed
df2=df1.loc[(df1['time_diff']/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h') >= 1) & (df1.val == df1.groupby('new_date').first().val[0])]
df3=df1.loc[(df1['time_diff']/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h') <= 1) & (df1.val == df1.shift_val)]

# Get the minimum within the group
df4=df2.append(df3).groupby(['new_date'], sort=False).min()

# drop unwanted columns
df4.drop(['new_time','shift_val','time_diff'],axis=1, inplace=True)

df4
```

**Output**

```
          subject_id    time_1     val
new_date            
2173-04-03  1   2173-04-03 17:00:00 5
2173-04-04  1   2173-04-04 16:00:00 5
2173-04-05  1   2173-04-05 04:00:00 8
```

Comment: Is there any reason one (last) row is missing in output? Anyway Appreciate your support. will try

Comment: there are three dates so three rows

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried with the other dataframe provided in the post. But am trying further. let me see whether i get the output

Comment: which dataframe it is not working? Can you share that in the Question? I think all the rules are implemented step by step

Comment: The other one (df1) which is mentioned in my question

Comment: Ok I now the reason why it is failing, Let me fix it in some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198660/discussion-between-ssmk-and-min2bro).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from datetime import timedelta

def f(x):
    dif = (x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[-1])//timedelta(minutes=1)
    return dif
df1['time_1']= pd.to_datetime(df1['time_1'])
df1['flag']= df1.val.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df1['t_d']=df1.groupby('flag')['time_1'].transform(f)
df1['date'] = df1['time_1'].dt.date
mask= df1['t_d'].ne(0)
dfa=df1[mask].groupby(['flag','date']).first().reset_index()
dfb=df1[~mask].groupby('date').first().reset_index().dropna(how='any')
df_f = dfa.merge(dfb, how='outer')
df_f.drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first', inplace=True)
df_f.drop(['flag','date','t_d'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_f
```

Output.

```
 subject_id     time_1         val
0   1   2173-04-03 12:35:00     5
1   1   2173-04-04 11:30:00     5
2   1   2173-04-05 16:00:00     5
5   1   2173-04-06 04:00:00     3
```

Comment: Upvoted anyway for the effort. Will try now and update the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, it produces the same output with `3` in the last row. It should be 4

Comment: val's for  2173-04-06 are 3,4&6 and not 4,4,4. So, i don't understand how 4 sustains for more than an hour.

Comment: If you see the time for those 3 records, it is 4-4.30 (30 mins), 4.30 - 8 (3 hr and 30 mins)

Comment: Did it help? any confusion?

Comment: look at the val column it is 3,4 & 6 so, where does 4-4.30 (30 mins) come? they are different val's. I don't get it.

Comment: Okay, here is the thing. I am looking at the `df1input` dataframe from screenshot.If you see the last 3 records which are of date `4/6/2173`. The first record time is `3` which starts at `4:00`.and goes on till `4:30` when 2nd record `4` is in place. it goes on till `8:00` when `6` is in place. You have to look at the time difference between these records

Comment: You can execute the dataframe (`df1`) code to verify yourself.

Comment: so, val's don't matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198658/discussion-between-ssmk-and-mohanys).

Comment: can't chat. firewall

Comment: I am not sure whether you got the question right. Both Time and val's matter. I am looking for > 1 hr criteria. So you have to be looking at both

Comment: your question says "Find all values (from val column) which have been same for more than 1 hour in each day", now you are saying val can change from 3 to 4 to 6 , but time matters.

Comment: Exactly. My question has `more than 1 hour`, so It's obvious that you should be checking at `time_1` column as well for time.

Comment: even if I assume we have to check time, the minimum value is 3 , not 4. or are you saying we have to look for difference between 2 times?

Comment: Yes, only if you look for difference between two times, you will know how long a value is sustained (same).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import timedelta

df1['time_1']= pd.to_datetime(df1['time_1'])
df1['date'] = df1['time_1'].dt.date
df1['t_d'] = df1.groupby(['date'])['time_1'].diff().shift(-1)
mask= df1['t_d']>pd.Timedelta(1,'h')
dfa=df1[mask]
dfb=df1[~mask].groupby('date').first().reset_index()
df_f = dfa.merge(dfb, how='outer')
df_f.drop_duplicates(subset='date', keep='first', inplace=True)
df_f.drop(['date','t_d'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_f.sort_values('time_1')
```

Comment: Sure. Am traveling back from work. Will try to check tonight and update it. You want to update your previous answer? Thanks for your effort.

Comment: for any given day, first time is the minimum time? is it not? I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an approach like below and it is working. Any suggestions are welcome

```
s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df.time_1-df.time_1.dt.normalize())
df['tdiff'] = df.groupby(df.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s)
df['t_d'] = df['tdiff'].dt.total_seconds()/3600
df['hr'] = df['time_1'].dt.hour
df['date'] = df['time_1'].dt.date
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time_1']).day

# here I get the freq and cumsum of each val for each day and each hour. Since sort = 'False', timeorder is retained as is

temp_1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['subject_id','date','hr','val'], sort=False)['t_d'].agg({'cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())

# here i remove the `hour` component and sum the value duration in same day but different hours (for example `5` was in 12th hour and 13th hour. we sum them)

temp_2 = pd.DataFrame(temp_1.groupby(['subject_id','date','val'], sort=False)['cumduration'].agg({'sum_of_cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())

# Later, I create a mask for `> 1` hr criteria  

mask = temp_2.groupby(['subject_id','date'])['sum_of_cumduration'].apply(lambda x: x > 1)
output_1 = pd.DataFrame(temp_2[mask].groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].min()).reset_index()

 # I check for `< 1 ` hr records here 

output_2 = pd.DataFrame(temp_2[~mask].groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].min()).reset_index()

 # I finally check for `subject_id` and `date` and then append
output = output_1.append(output_2[~output_2['subject_id'].isin(output_1['subject_id'])])

output
```

[image]

[image]